# Deus Ex Machina?

Tags: story-identification, virtual-worlds

I'm looking for a sci-fi story I read about 20 years ago.  It includes the following elements:

- A lab, and a computer simulation of the universe or earth.
  Evolution (possibly).
- A simulation created with the first simulation by scientists within the first simulation.
- A real world lab technician/scientist entering the simulation(s).

I would appreciate some help finding this story, thanks.

Comment: This is an incredibly common trope. Can you be more specific? http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CityInABottle

Comment: For example, this novel fits your description almost perfectly; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulacron-3

Comment: Can you remember anything about the events of the story, the hero, any villains, the names of the simulation, anything remarkable that happened inside the sim?

Comment: Was there some sort of deus ex machina plot twist? What does the title of this question have anything to do with the story/question?

Comment: There is a movie http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thirteenth_Floor with this story from 1999. It is base on the book http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulacron-3

Comment: Wow, thanks for the v.quick response.  This story is not "The Thirteenth Floor" or Simulacron-3 or "Permutation-City".  I think the name of the story was Deus Ex Machina or something akin to that.  Major plot develpments, The people with the simulated world creating their own simulation, then the people from the real world entering the simulated worlds.  Please keep asking questions it may jog my memory.  BTW this was pre Matrix.

Comment: PS I read this online around 1996/7.  I don't think it was published...

Comment: If it wasn't published, where did you read it?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was I read it online.  I'm currently searching the web using the criteria I gave using 1998 as a starting point and moving backwards...

Comment: Was it a short story? Were the scientist inside aware that they were in a simulation? Anything else you can remember?

Comment: I'm not sure if it was a short story, I think I recall several chapters...  The scientists inside the simulation were not aware of their state (at least initially).  The scientists in the real world were able to enter the simulated world.

Comment: It was very similar to Greg Egans "Crystal Nights" except for the avatars were humanoid (I believe), but there was definitely a sim with a sim scenario

Comment: I do know one story that seems to fit all this, out in 90s even, but its interactive.

Comment: What was the name of the the story Radhil?

Comment: "A simulation created with the first simulation by scientists within the first simulation." This line takes a couple reads to get straight in your head. ^_^

Comment: I'll glady clarify again:  Scientist created a simulation of the earth (or the universe & earth) and watch evolution un fold.  The occupants of the simulated earth evolve to a technological level which allows them to create their own simulated earth, and study this.  Scientist from the real world learn how to enter/interact with their simulated world and also the sim world within it.  It was an interesting read but i can't recall if I ever finished it.

Comment: Maybe "Donnerjack" by Roger Zelazny ?

Comment: Sounds a little like "Picoverse" by Robert Metzger, but the publication date on that one is 2002!